# Numbers next to related questions (on the right) not updated?

Tags: support, related-questions

When you browse a question on Stack Overflow, you have a whole bunch of related questions on the right.

For some reason, they are WAY WAY out of date (so for example clicking on one that says it has 0 answers, takes me to the question, which has been answered several times, voted up, and been marked as answered).

Any ideas why?

Example: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776323/how-to-bind-an-array-in-mvvmcross?rq=1) link says 0 answers:

[image: List of related questions]

yet it's been answered and marked as that when you open it.

[image: Answer on a specific question]

Shame I closed the one with multiple answers and upvotes ...

Comment: [Caching!](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelb958/vSfXT/show/#caching)

Comment: [IE](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelb958/vSfXT/show/#IE) ! (Cheers for the laugh though :)

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: **Where** did you take that screenshot? You only provided where the highlighted link leads to, so I cannot verify the other links.

Comment: Was it [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739446/mvvmcross-navigation-parameters)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yep, that was the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading those numbers wrong, I am afraid. Those numbers are **not** answer counts. If you mouse over the number, the tool tip says:

[image: Vote score tooltip]

And indeed, the question you linked to has score 0.

I verified all the other scores on the [post in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739446/mvvmcross-navigation-parameters) and all the question scores are up-to-date.

Comment: Gosh I feel silly ... I never hoovered above the numbered, Just assumed they are answers for some reason ... You're right, those numbers are the upvotes on the Question, nothing to do with the answers